# How to add argument to this slightly complicated method call?

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
rv.append(get_quest_guide_char("lindsey", **{"marker":  ["items cake_slice","items bottle pepelepsi","items apple"] for x in [1] * (game.location == lindsey.location)}))
```

Baisically, how it works is,

If game.location does not equal lindsey.location, then the result call looks like this, only one argument is passed and that is the lindsey argument.

```
rv.append(get_quest_guide_char("lindsey"))
```

If it is true however, then that second argument is added like this

```
rv.append(get_quest_guide_char("lindsey", marker = ["items cake_slice","items bottle pepelepsi","items apple"]))
```

How do I insert a third condition to add if the result is true? The code I tried looks like this and it doesn't work.

```
rv.append(get_quest_guide_char("lindsey", **{"marker_sector": "right_bottom", "marker":  ["items cake_slice","items bottle pepelepsi","items apple"] for x in [1] * (game.location == lindsey.location)}))
```

where the third argument would be marker_sector = "right_bottom"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you are trying to do, try this:

```
rv.append(get_quest_guide_char("lindsey", marker_sector="right_bottom", **{"marker":  ["items cake_slice","items bottle pepelepsi","items apple"] for x in [1] * (game.location == lindsey.location)}))
```

It would add the other kwarg without the condition and simplify the code.

However, I recommend you to refactor this piece of code, maybe defining the argument on a variable outside the append.

```
if game.location == lindsey.location:
    marker = ["items cake_slice", "items bottle pepelepsi", "items apple"]
else:
    marker = None

rv.append(get_quest_guide_char("lindsey", marker_sector="right_bottom", marker=marker))
```